# convert complex JSON to dataset using JSON schema

Tags: json, vb.net

I have some complex JSON data (1-many relationships) and both a text file and URL reference to the schema.  I need to convert the data to a System.Data.Dataset, perserving the data types and relationships in the schema.

At present, I've been able to create a dataset by converting the data to an XML document, but it does not read the schema and therefore the data columns are all text and the data relationship is not preserved.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.IO

    Dim xml As XmlDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\jsondata.txt"), "rootnode")
    Dim ds As New DataSet("Json Data")
    Dim xr As XmlReader = New XmlNodeReader(xml)
ds.ReadXml(xr)
```

My programming language is VB.NET.

At this point I can see all the data in the appropriate tables, but the relationships are assigned by the converter and all the data is text.  I don't see a way of referencing the schema in this or any other Json.net method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you "jsondata.txt" ... or a post a link to it if it is large

Comment: Sorry, I missed one line of code - see amended code above.

Comment: @regattamaster If you don't want something distributed, you shouldn't post it publicly on the internet. If you have sensitive data, either create a non-sensitive version which still has the problem, or hire a contractor that you can trust/have sign stuff before showing them sensitive stuff.